# Ag-grid - disabling Side button

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

fairly Simple question regarding the new balham theme on Ag-grid.

Id like to disable the side button and the tool panel completely as shown in the link below: 
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel/

I can hide the tool panel, but cannot hide the side button labelled 'Columns' and was wondering if there was a simple way to do so? Many thanks

Comment: does the below answer solve your problem? If so could you accept it so other users having the same question can be benefited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the property showToolPanel to false in ag-grid

```
[showToolPanel]="false"


<ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    id="myGrid"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [enableSorting]="true"
    [showToolPanel]="false"
    [enableFilter]="true"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

and if you completely want to remove the columns tool panel then you can override the css

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-tool-panel{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You can also set the `toolPanelSuppressSideButtons` to `true` if you want to suppress the side buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In ag-grid v19, the option is sideBar = false ([sideBar docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/))